# Como faço para atualizar um Widget atraves de um controller em um campo de OnChanged?

Tags: mobile, flutter, dart

Não consigo atualizar um widget de Text que deveria mostrar a soma de dois TextFormField a medida que alguem fosse o alterando (OnChanged). O que posso estar fazendo errado? (Já coloquei SetState pra todo lado e nada deu certo)

Abaixo, um dos TextFormField:

```
child: TextFormField(
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _ComprPeca = value;
                              });
                            },
                            controller: myController,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'Comprimento da Peça'),
                          ),
```

O container que possui o Text que quero mudar:

```
Container conteiner = Container(
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Expanded(child: Text(_ComprPeca + _ComprLanca))));
```

O Controller que delcarei:

```
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myController.addListener(_printLatestValue);
  }

    @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the controller when the widget is removed from the widget tree.
    // This also removes the _printLatestValue listener.
    myController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  } 

  _printLatestValue() {
    print("Second text field: ${myController.text}");
    print("comprimento lanca: " + _ComprLanca);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você já está trabalhando com um `TextEditingController`, não há necessidade de pegar o texto diretamente pelo `OnChanged()`, isso aqui deve resolver teu problema:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  );
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  TextEditingController controller_1 = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController controller_2 = TextEditingController();
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            (
              (double.tryParse(controller_1.text)??0) + 
              (double.tryParse(controller_2.text)??0)
            ).toString()),
          TextField(
            controller: controller_1,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Campo 1"
            ),
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState((){});
            },
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: controller_2,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Campo 2"
            ),            
            onChanged: (String value) {
              setState((){});
            },
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

**Explicando**

Como o *controller* retorna o que foi digitado no `TextField` como *String* é necessário você fazer a conversão para *Integer* ou *Double*.
No meu exemplo eu fiz a conversão dos valores para *Double* da seguinte forma:

> (double.tryParse(controller_2.text)??0)

Fiz dessa forma para que se caso você digite algum carácter diferente de um número o seu aplicativo não trave.

O `tryParse` como o próprio nome diz, tenta converter o valor para *double* e caso não consiga ele retorna NULL. E caso retorne NULL eu já tratei com o `?? 0` que transforma o retorno NULO no valor 0 (Zero).

Você pode testear o funcionamento pelo [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/), só copiar e colar lá.

Comment: Pelo que entendi o autor da pergunta deseja saber como faz para somar dois números digitados e exibir em um Text. Nesse caso acredito ser interessante mencionar a conversão de String para Double e (talvez) o uso de multiplos controllers.

Comment: @Naslausky Lendo novamente, realmente eu havia entendido errado... Mas já ajustei a resposta de acordo com sua dica.

Comment: Perfeito pessoal!
Meu problema estava no fato de que quando eu somava os dois valores, caso um deles ficasse vazio a soma não acontecia. E eu so pude perceber isso depois que coloquei um Try Catch dentro dessa soma, o debug não pegava esse erro e deixava tudo funcionar normalmente. Fiz desta forma e consegui solucionar:
try { _ResultadoGuindaste = (_ComprLanca.isEmpty ? 0.0: double.parse(_ComprLanca)) *1.25 +double.parse(_ComprPeca) / 2;} catch (e) {print(e); }

Muito Obrigado!